# Google Maps iOS SDK for Directions

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to use the Google Maps iOS SDK to show a user the direction from his position to another location **within** my app (i.e. in another UIView, and not using the URL Scheme to pass the direction request to the Google Map app)?

Many of my users don't have the Google Map app on iPhone, however the directions Google provide are much more accurate than Apple's map, hence my necessity to show the direction within my app.

Comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To display Google Maps (even using the SDK) users need to have the Google Maps app installed.

You can test whether this is the case using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"comgooglemaps://"]];
```

If it returns false, you could prompt users to download Google Maps.

The SDK can be used to display a poly line from the users current location to some other point, **however** it cannot (at this stage anyway) provide turn-by-turn directions inside the app, for that you do need to use the URL scheme.

Comment: No, I don't have the Google Maps App installed on my iPhone and I have apps using Google Maps inside the apps.